# CodeRally installation on mac osx

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, code-rally

As there is no OSX specific version, I downloaded the Linux version. Unzipped it and launched the launchpad.app.

I see a java applet on screen, but when I click on install code rally, I get no response.

Please advise on steps to install. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[From CodeRally Manual Installation page:](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/manually_installing_code_rally?lang=en)

> If you want to install Code Rally but do not want to use the installer
>   from our downloads page or are using OSX then the following
>   instructions will guide you through the install process.

Basically you need to build the code manually instead of using an installer. Weird choice from IBM side that there is no installer for OSX, but that's life, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to build the code yourself - [the manual steps for installation](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/manually_installing_code_rally?lang=en) basically involves downloading the different components yourself and installing them.